# How to compare 2JTL files

Tags: jmeter, go-cd

In GoCD how we can compare two jtl file to find the average response time difference.
On executing jmeter script through pipeline and on generating the JTL file, want to compare the jtl file from last release and find the average reaponse time differe for each request

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin:

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/

It allows to compare 2 jtl/csv files (previous vs last run)

It will  provide a CSV file which compares the 2 tests.

Comment: Whether this will compare & provide the result, so that i can publish in GoCD report.